# Definition of arg$(x)$ where $x\in\Bbb R^d$ and further properties.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, transformation

In a text I am reading occured the reflection in the line $\Bbb R^d z$:

For a fixed $z\in\Bbb R ^d $ we define
$$T_z : \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R ^d , T_z (x) := 2\langle x,z_0 \rangle z_0 - x$$
where $z_0 := \frac z {\Vert z \Vert}$.
Now there was stated the following: Let $x\in\Bbb R^d$, then

$$\text{arg}(T_z (x)) = 2\text{arg}(z) - \text{arg}(x).$$
What is $x\mapsto \text{arg}(x)$?